# Undefined symbols of the architechture x86_64

Tags: c++

ok I am learning c++ and I got this error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Point::set(int, int)", referenced from:
      Point::Point(int, int)in ccHkya9E.o
  "Point::add(Point const&)", referenced from:
      Point::operator+(Point const&)in ccHkya9E.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

here is my code

```
#include<iostream>

 using namespace std;

 class Point {
 private:
   int x, y;
 public:
   Point() {}
   Point(int new_x, int new_y) {set(new_x, new_y);}
   Point (const Point & src) {set(src.x, src.y);}

 //Operations
   Point add (const Point &pt);
   Point sub (const Point &pt);
   Point operator+(const Point &pt) {return add(pt);}
   Point operator-(const Point &pt) {return sub(pt);}
 //other member functions
   void set(int new_x, int new_y);
   int get_x() const {return x;}
   int get_y() const {return y;}
 };

 int main() {
   Point point1(20,20);
   Point point2(0,5);
   Point point3(-10, 25);
   Point point4=point1+point2+point3;

   cout<<"the point is"<<point4.get_x();
   cout<<","<<point4.get_y()<<"."<<endl;
   return 0;
 }
```

any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please don't put line numbers in your code like this; it makes it a pain to copy-and-paste into an editor!

Comment: Well, where do you define `Point::set`?  Do you define it?  You certainly don't define it anywhere in the code you posted.

Answer (score 7):

You only declared the functions:

```
void set(int new_x, int new_y);
Point add (const Point &pt);
```

But You did not provide definitions for them. So the linker cannot find their definitions and complains about it, The compiler tells you to provide a definition for those two functions, and you should.

An empty(which does nothing) definition of the functions look like:

```
void set(int new_x, int new_y)
{

}
Point add (const Point &pt)
{
    Point temp;
    return temp;
}
```

**Disclaimer:** You should replace these definitions with your actual implementation, The above shall just let you compile and link sucessfully(not work as you want to)

Comment: What is definition of the function? How should it look like?